# AWS RDS Restore HEADERONLY from S3

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-backups

From RDS AWS, I am not able to restore a database **header only** from S3 bucket:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY  FROM  DISK  = N'arn:aws:s3::myBucket/myDB.bak'
```

Just to check access, I can restore the full database without errors :

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
@restore_db_name='myDBName', 
@s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3::myBucket/myDB.bak'
```

Is this even possible? what am I missing? Why **restore header only** is not working ? Any other alternatives ?

[image]

Comment: Those statements aren't alike. In the first statement you are trying to use `RESTORE DATABASE` against a cloud hosted file (which won't work), in the latter you are using a bespoke procedure (which appear to be created by [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html)) `rds_restore_database`. In the linked documentation I can't see anything about getting the header from the file, though that doesn't mean there isn't. Perhaps it's a different procedure (I don't have a AWS instance to investigate into whether such a procedure exists).

Comment: AWS procedures don't appear to have a "header only" option. If we knew what the code is for `rds_restore_database` then we might be able to construct it, but not sure how to get the source code

Comment: @Charlieface, exactly. How the "rds_restore_database" works ?

Comment: The rds_restore_database procedure is documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html There's no obvious equivalent of "header only", but I'm not familiar with what that option does, so will leave it to someone else to answer more definitively.